# what is CALL F000:01AC in a programmable timer using 8253

Tags: microcontroller

The question is regarding the peripheral 8253 for 8086
There's a code in assembly language for a timer using 8253.I cant't understand one part of the code which is to call the routine(CALL F000:01AC).Why is this required ?

Comment: you have to look at the code that is being called to see what it does.

Comment: It look like a call to ROM/BIOS code. Is it trying to print out a value, trigger a clock tick .. .?

Comment: The program is basically to see the working of counter using 8253. CALL F000:01AC is a call routine i suppose but i cannot understand why are we using it in the code.